# Reg Ex to find field more than n characters in CSV file opened in notepad++

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a very big CSV file 200000+ records.

Need to search a string more than 100 characters.

RegEx to find field more than n characters in CSV file opened in Notepad++

Tried the following .. but not working

```
(?:,[^,\r\n]*){100,}$
```

Comment: Perhaps like this? `(?<=,|^)[^,\r\n]{100,}` https://regex101.com/r/WgEq0T/1

Comment: `*` matches zero or more. Doesn't make much sense to use with `{}`. Your regex requires more than a hundred commas before it matches. Just `,[^,\r\n]{100,}` may be enough

Answer (score 0):

You need something like

```
[^,\r\n]{100,}
```

What you were repeating 100+ times was a field of *any* length, preceded by a comma.

I'm not sure about the `\r` and `\n` in the character class, they may not be needed (that depends on Notepad++). In case they are not needed, the expression simplifies to

```
[^,]{100,}
```

Of course, the above regex is based on the assumption that you don't have commas (`,`) *inside* CSV fields and that fields are not enclosed in quotes. To handle that case with a regex is still possible under other simplifying assumptions (i.e., excluding edge cases). I'll also assume, based on your attempt, that the field you are looking for is not the first of a row, so that we can say it's preceded by a comma:

```
(?<=,)(?:"[^"]{100,}"|[^",][^,]{99,})
```

(the `(?<=,)` is a "positive lookbehind" of a comma)